# mysql doesn't support all symbols from range U+0000..U+FFFF

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 VARCHAR(255));
```

Then, be it `ruby`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'json'
require 'sequel'
require 'mysql2'
DB = Sequel.connect(
    :adapter => 'mysql2',
    :database => 'd1',
    :user => '<user>',
    :password => '<password>',
    :encoding => 'utf8')
v1 = '{"a":"b\ud83c\udf4ec"}'
v2 = JSON.parse(v1)
p v2['a']
DB[:t1].truncate
DB[:t1].insert(f1: v2['a']);
p DB[:t1].first[:f1]
```

or `php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=d1', '<user>', '<password>', [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
]);
$dbh->exec('TRUNCATE TABLE t1');
$v1 = '{"a":"b\ud83c\udf4ec"}';
$v2 = json_decode($v1);
var_dump($v2->a);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (?)");
$sth->execute([$v2->a]);
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM t1");
var_dump($sth->fetch()['f1']);
```

what gets in the database is `b`. I'm running `mysql-5.1` and the documentation [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode.html):

> MySQL 5.1 supports two character sets for storing Unicode data:
>
> - `ucs2`, the UCS-2 encoding of the Unicode character set using 16 bits per character.
> - `utf8`, a UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to three bytes per character.
>
> These two character sets support the characters from the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) of Unicode Version 3.0. BMP characters have these characteristics:
>
> - Their code values are between 0 and 65535 (or `U+0000` .. `U+FFFF`).

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**

```
$ mysql -BNe 'SHOW CREATE TABLE t1' d1
t1  CREATE TABLE `t1` (\n  `f1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: can you check your table `COLLATION`? it should be `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8_general_ci`. When you created the table it used MySQL default collation, which is usually `latin1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears those two escape sequences represent only one character: [RED APPLE (U+1F34E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F34E/index.htm). The first one being a surrogate. And [surrogates are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates):

> The UCS uses surrogates to address characters **outside the initial Basic Multilingual Plane** without resorting to more than 16 bit byte representations.

So that must be it, the resulting character is outside the `BMP`. And is not supported by `mysql`'s `utf8` character set as such.

Answer (score 1):

in my MySQL 5.1 (from debian) doing

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 VARCHAR(255));
```

is effectively creating a LATIN1 table :

```
mysql> show CREATE TABLE t1 ;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t1    | CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `f1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So please check first that your MySQL really defaults to UTF-8.

Then, MySQL is known to NOT be able to store every character from BMP table. I don't find references about that, but saw it earlier.

So much that from mysql 5.5.3 introduced a new utf8mb4 full-unicode support character set as statu As stated here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html

Finally, even if BMP is **saying** they are between 0 and 0xFFFF it doesn't mean they are using **all** of this space as stated here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane

Comment: The field is in `utf8`, please see my updated answer.

Comment: are your caracters above in the **used** parts of BMP? If they are unused characters or outside BMP, MySQL will silently ignore them (and the rest of the string too...) see my notes on using MySQL-5.5 and utf8mb4